# Devise: How to save a 8 character hexadecimal string into the users table upon registration using SecureRandom.hex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When a new user signs up I would like to create a unique URL for them by creating a random hexadecimal string using SecureRandom.hex(4). This unique string will be saved in a column in the users table called url. Then I can load specific user data via user/url (instead of user.id or user.user_name). I seem to easily be able to add new fields for user input but I am struggling to work out how to save it with the record automatically upon creation. 
How could I implement this using Devise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
# This is a registered user or guest
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :omniauthable

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    super
    @hex ||= SecureRandom.hex(4)
  end
end
```

Here we override the 'normal' initialize method of the User class, call the normal behaviour of its parent `super` and then set the value that we need.

Note that the user is not saved yet, he is just initialized this way.

`@hex ||= SecureRandom.hex(4)` means that the hex is set to a new value unless there already is one (`intialize` is also called for existing records)

p.s. Just curious, why would you do this with hex and not uuid?

UPDATE:

Note that the code above does not check if the hex has already been used. To do this you'd have to create a method that checks for this like so:

```
def initialize(attributes = {})
    super
    @hex ||= unique_hex
  end

  def unique_hex
    hex = SecureRandom.hex(4)
    return unique_hex if User.exists?(hex: hex)
    hex
  end
```

What this does is first create a new hex, then check if a `User` exists that has this hex, if not we return the new hex, if there IS a user that has this hex we call `unique_hex` again to attempt to find a unique hex again.

Update2:

Lets say you want to link to your user now. One way to achieve this would be to define this method in your User model:

```
def to_param
  # We will use 'parameterize' here to make sure we can use it in a url
  hex.parameterize # or use uuid here
end
```

This way when you use `user_path(@user)` you will get something like: `users/the-used-hex`

In your controller you can/must now replace the queries for your User with `User.find_by(hex: params[:id])`. Note how we have no 'hacked' our `params[:id]`, this might not be very clean. You could use ['dynamic segments'](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments) instead in combination with [the overriding of named parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters), but I think for now you'd already get some experience out of the `to_param` method.

Note2: You will probably also have to update the finder methods of the Devise controllers to use `find_by(hex: params[:id])` since now your User model will return the hex as its id for urls.

An alternative would be to only use the hex in the path when you need it. To do this you can call `user_path('whatever_you_want')`, this will return `users/whatever_you_want`. In your case you could use `user_path(@user.hex)`. The advantage is that you haven't overwritten anything that your Devise controllers still use and you can still use `User.find_by(hex: params[:id])` in your own controllers.

Comment: Great thanks for the help. And how do I set :url to the @hex value?

Comment: I didn't think of using uuid, would you recommend that instead?

Comment: @Hotjam It depends on your reasoning behind not using 'simple' ids. If you want pretty urls uuids might not be the right thing if you don't like the way they look (I think they look fine). If you wanted to prevent people from guessing ids of objects and therefore wanted randoms I'd rethink my security model ([security through obscurity is bad practice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)). The advantage of uuids is that there is [less of a chance that there will be clashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates)

Comment: @Hotjam What do you mean by 'setting the :url' ?

Comment: Yeah the reason for it was just to avoid the headache of collisions! So I have a url column in the table, how can I assign the results of the unique_hex to the url in the table? Originally I was going to somehow set it in the controller and have the model validate_uniqueness_of, but your edit also looks good. Thanks. (Apologise I am self-taught up to this point)

Comment: Is this url value something like 'http://website.com/users/the_hex_of_user'? In that case you wouldn't need to save it on the user model, you can generate it on the fly whenever you need it: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters (I'll update my answer some more)

Comment: Yes exactly like that. I just need the auto-generated hex to save in the url column of the users table when they submit the registration form via devise

Comment: @Hotjam As I now added to the answer I wouldn't save the url on the user record, but instead I'd just generate the url whenever you need it (in views, controllers, etc) that way you won't have to run big messy migrations on your User table whenever your urls change (other domain, other routes, etc)

Comment: You've been great Mosselman, thanks for the detailed responses and updates. I'll give your suggestions a go.

Comment: @Hotjam No problem, glad to help. Also, don't worry about being self-taught, we all are :), even if you get some basics from courses/education you still have to do it and experiment with new things, and you are doing that so you have nothing to apologise about :)

Answer (score 0):

I personally would avoid doing this in devise.

If you want to do it manually

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_validation :set_uuid, on: :create
    validates_uniqueness_if :uuid

    private

    def set_uuid
        self.uuid = SecureRandom.hex(4)
    end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @user = User.find_by(uuid: params[:id])
    end
end
```

OR

This is gem:

https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Comment: The downside to this method is that you can't use the User's 'hex/uuid' until he is saved. The beauty of uuids is that you can already start to use their uniqueness before they are persisted to the database. Also, using before_actions adds to making your code a bit harder to reason about so they should be used sparingly.